# How to catch the search query when the user comes from a search engine to the web site?

Tags: seo, google-search

Is it possible to transfer a search query to the url or to catch it somehow in order to show more relevant similar products on the landing page ?
For ex.

- if the search query is "red tiles" we would like to show other variants of red tiles
- if the search query is "Versace tiles" we would like to show other variants from the same brand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No. You can't for organic search queries.

Passing the originating search query to the destination website was a feature discontinued by Google (and other search engines followed suit) almost a decade ago.

If you're running Ads, then yes (although they've starting hiding some of that in certain situations). That is possible. But it's not available for organic search.

Comment: For some history see all the questions around [not provided](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=not%20provided) which what the Google Analytics keyword report shows after Google stopped sending the keywords to websites.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the originating search query to the destination website when using Google Ads?

Comment: @VasylKosteniuk I'm not sure. You can certainly pass the keyword that triggered the ad onto the receiving website (that's how Analytics picks up the data, after all). You used to be able to include the search query as well, but I've not used that feature in a while. It'll be under the manual tagging options for the final URL, if it's still available.